# Adding codes to the newly added tab

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

I am doing a tracker where I have two main tabs - "Home" and "MasterFile".

**"Home"** is the tab sheet where they will place the date today in cell B2 (since every month we will be updating this).
**"MasterFile"** is the template file.

The idea of the tool is to create two new sheets, copying the MasterFile as the new sheets with different filenames - **"WFH + (date in B2 cell)"sheet** and **"MasterFile + (date in B2 cell)"Sheet**.

People can edit the "WFH + (date in B2 cell)"sheet. Any changes made will changes the color of the cell as to reference to the "MasterFile + (date in B2 cell)"Sheet.

*Example:*
Cell B2 value is  March 2024. Two new sheet tab will be generated - *WFH March 2024* and *MasterFile March2024*.

How do I input the coding of "worksheet_change" in the newly added tab?
It should be added under "WFH + (date in B2 cell)"sheet every time we add new data.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub NewData()

Dim MasterFileWk As Worksheet

Set MasterFileWk = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterFile")

MasterFileWk.Copy after:=Workbooks("WFH tracker.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("WFH tracker.xlsm").Worksheets.Count)

ActiveSheet.Name = "MasterFile " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B2")

'second copy
MasterFileWk.Copy after:=Workbooks("WFH tracker.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("WFH tracker.xlsm").Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "WFH " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B2")

On Error Resume Next

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterFile " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B2")).Protect

End Sub
```

I am trying to insert the below code in the newly created *"WFH + (date in B2 cell)".

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim WFHDate As Workbook
'    Set WFHDate = Sheets("Home").Range("B2").Value

    Set rngCell = Sheets("MasterFile " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B2").Value).Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)
    ActiveWindow.ThisWorksheets("WFH " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B2")).Select
    If rngCell <> Target Then
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)
    Else
        If rngCell = Target Then
            Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: In a worksheet code module you can use `Me` to refer to the associated worksheet.  I'm not really sure what's going on in that Change event though.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams will take a look at that and research more about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello please try the below code but first make the appropriate reference by going to the visual basic editor -> Tools -> References and checking the box next to: "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility ..."

```
Option Explicit
Sub NewData()

Dim MasterFileWk As Worksheet
Set MasterFileWk = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterFile")


MasterFileWk.Copy after:=Workbooks("WFH tracker.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("WFH tracker.xlsm").Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "MasterFile " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B2")

MasterFileWk.Copy after:=Workbooks("WFH tracker.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("WFH tracker.xlsm").Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "WFH " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B2")

On Error Resume Next

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterFile " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B2")).Protect

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim str As String
Dim strCodeModuleName As String
Dim xLine As Long

Set wb = Workbooks("WFH tracker.xlsm")
str = "WFH " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B2")
strCodeModuleName = wb.Sheets(str).CodeName

With wb.VBProject.VBComponents(strCodeModuleName).CodeModule
xLine = .CreateEventProc("Change", "Worksheet")
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "  Dim rngCell As Range"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "  Dim WFHDate As Workbook"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "  'Set WFHDate = Sheets(""Home"").Range(""B2"").Value"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "  Set rngCell = Sheets(""MasterFile "" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(""Home"").Range(""B2"").Value).Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "  ActiveWindow.ThisWorksheets(""WFH "" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(""Home"").Range(""B2"")).Select"
                xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "  If rngCell <> Target Then"
                xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "  Target.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)"
                xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "Else"
                xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "  If rngCell = Target Then"
                xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "       Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)"
                xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "  End If"
                xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "End If"
End With

End Sub
```

Another option would be to export the the Worksheet_Change module as a .cls file into a shared folder that all users will have access to. Once exported, it will look like this:

```
VERSION 1.0 ' delete this line
BEGIN ' delete this line
  MultiUse = -1 ' delete this line
END ' delete this line
Attribute VB_Name = "Sheet1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim WFHDate As Workbook
'    Set WFHDate = Sheets("Home").Range("B2").Value

    Set rngCell = Sheets("MasterFile " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B2").Value).Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)
  ActiveWindow.ThisWorksheets("WFH " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B2")).Select
        If rngCell <> Target Then

        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)
    Else
        If rngCell = Target Then
            Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

you will need to delete the first four lines and re-save the .cls file. Next, you can try importing the .cls into the sheet like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub NewData()

Dim MasterFileWk As Worksheet
Set MasterFileWk = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterFile")


MasterFileWk.Copy after:=Workbooks("WFH tracker.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("WFH tracker.xlsm").Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "MasterFile " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B2")

MasterFileWk.Copy after:=Workbooks("WFH tracker.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("WFH tracker.xlsm").Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "WFH " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B2")

On Error Resume Next

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterFile " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B2")).Protect

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim str As String
Dim strCodeModuleName As String
Dim xLine As Long

Set wb = Workbooks("WFH tracker.xlsm")
str = "WFH " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B2")
strCodeModuleName = wb.Sheets(str).CodeName

With wb.VBProject.VBComponents(strCodeModuleName).CodeModule
.AddFromFile ("C:\Users\LIUIO\OneDrive - LANXESS Deutschland GmbH\Dokumente\Stack Overflow\Sheet_Change.cls") ' update to your file path
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i get the idea however for some reason the code won't work/ not copied in the added new sheet tab. I appreciate this though cause it is a good start for me to explore and tweak. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Jen, if you explain which section of the code is not working, I'd be happy to assist with adjusting it! Question, are you working in 2 different workbooks? Or is "WFH tracker.xlsm" the only workbook that is open/ the source wb?

Comment: Also, did you enable the reference for Extensibility? That is crucial.

Comment: Ive updated my answer with another option for importing the code. Please let me know if you have any questions or need help.

Comment: Thank you Kurt. My apologies for just getting back due to personal reason. The code work after I added the reference for extensibility. Thank you so much for the patience and help. Kudos to you

Comment: Jen, I am happy I could help. My best wishes and I hope all is well. Cheers